# Inspect element support on flutter web apps

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have been trying to integrate a web based product tour/on-boarding plugin which will help a new user to understand the application without any external intervention. I cam across this plugin :
https://getuserflow.com/ which works well with html websites, I tried integrating this with flutter web app and it fails to detect any element as flutter doesnt support inspect using chrome for some reason.

Whenever I try to inspect a flutter web app it shows this:
[image: Inspect on flutter web app]

It is almost impossible to inspect individual elements same as we can do on other web apps developed in angular or php.

**Is there a way on flutter web to enable web inspect so that the plugin will be supported?**

Comment: does the devtools work? https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector

Comment: Thanks for reply, Devtools is for internal inspecting, It wont solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: No this is not possible in its current form in flutter for web. Because flutter converts your widgets into different forms of canvas and svg tags in them. It is difficult to precisely locate your respective element for a widget say a button, if thats what you are looking for. But I do believe there are such tools specifically designed for flutter. Should google it out a bit.

Comment: There are some as I found in fluttergems.dev [here](https://fluttergems.dev/feature-discovery-coach-marks/)

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions and information

Answer (score 1):

Inspect element works with HTML and CSS files. And flutter converts your dart code to canvas, that's why we can't do inspect element.

And I don't think it is possible as of version 2.

Comment: It’s canvas, not just JS. JS can also do html which can be inspected. But canvas cannot.

Answer (score 0):

To make Flutter generate the full HTML tree and thus accessibility tree, you have to add `SemanticsBinding.instance.ensureSemantics();` after `runApp(const MyApp());`
I have also seen `RendererBinding.instance.ensureSemantics()` but not sure what the difference is...

Comment: as alternative i think it is also possible to use "`--web-renderer html`" - https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers#command-line-options

Answer (score -2):

**Automating Testing for Flutter Flow Web App**

If you're trying to automate testing for a Flutter Flow web application, there's a workaround to deal with its canvas-like structure. Here's a step-by-step guide:

---

**Inspect Visible Elements:**

- Open your Flutter Flow web app in a browser.
- Use the browser's developer tools to inspect visible elements.

**Identify Key Elements:**

- Look for elements like buttons, input fields, etc., with unique
  attributes.

**Reveal Elements for Interaction:**

- Inside the flt-glass-pane within body/flutter-view, there's a
  shadow-root.
- Find the flt-semantics-placeholder element and click it once.
- This will reveal the flt-semantics-host which contains all the
  elements you want to interact with.

**Locate Elements for Interaction:**

- Now that elements are revealed, you can locate them using their
  attributes.
- For example, find elements like #myButtonId or .myInputClass within
  flt-semantics-host.

**Perform Actions:**

- Simulate actions like entering text into an input field or clicking a
  button.
- For example, myInput.value = 'Test Input'; myButton.click();

**Verify Results:**

- Check for expected changes or responses in your app.

For more detailed steps and examples, you can check out my blog post [here](https://www.alphabin.co/blog/overcoming-flutterflow-dom-element-challenge). It provides a deeper dive into this process.

This approach should help automate testing for your Flutter Flow web app despite its canvas-like structure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).